# what is set() in 2d arrays?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm looking up stuff to learn how to check if a 2D array is full, and I came across one that uses `x.set(...)` to verify if the 2d array is full. What does it do?

Here's the example I found:

```
for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++){
for(int col = 0; col < 3; col++){
x.set(row,col,'A');
}
}
```

Then it returns true if the array is full.

Also, here's my current code:

```
for (int row = 0; row < rows; ++row)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < cols; ++col)
        {
            if (arr[row][col] > 0)
            {
                ++xcell;
            }
        }
    }
```

I only have a counter and a conditional statement hanging because I was thinking of comparing the counter with the array's size (so if it's equal to that then it means the array is full and another move cannot be made), but the array is 2d so I'm kind of stuck and not sure which next step to take.

If anyone could drop a few hints, it would be very appreciated.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you just want to write boolean method that returns true if all elements of 2D arrays are greater than 0?

Comment: If you want us to explain what the code containng x.set() does and how it works, you'd better show us this code. We're not extra-lucid wizards. Arrays don't have a set() method, that's all we can tell.

Comment: @JBNizet sorry for that, see my edit

Comment: And what's the type of `x`? How is it declared? And what makes you think that this is used to check that an array is full?

Comment: @AlexR Sort of, yes. The 0 means the index is vacant. If the index contains a value other than 0, then it means the index/slot is occupied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I will give yo a tip.

```
boolean isFull(int[][] arr) {
    for (int[] line : arr) {
        for (int elem : line) {
            if (elem == 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

I do not want to explain anything here. I am sure you can understand this code yourself. It should help you to start. But I'd recommend you to find a good tutorial that teaches basics of programming step-by-step. Good luck.

Comment: I found a way on my own already, setting up a counter at initialization of array then decrementing it every time a player takes his turn, but thanks for this!

Comment: @user3026693, take a look on my example. You do not have to iterate over whole array to check that its first element is 0. It is enough to find one element `==0` to return `false`.